# Could not inflate and Didn't find class Behavior of android support design BottomSheetBehavior

Tags: android, android-design-library, bottom-sheet, androiddesignsupport

I am trying to implement bottom modal sheet to my main project. I successfully did it in a single demo project. But when I am applying same structure to my main  project then the app crashes with the following error:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Could not
>   inflate Behavior subclass
>   android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inflate Behavior subclass android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior
>
> AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't
>   find class "android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior" on
>   path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example........]]

I tried the previously stated `app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"` in my xml but it didn't work.

In the demo project the bottom sheet works properly in nested parent view.

My main project dependencies are - (added to app build.gradle)

```
    def lifecycle_version = "2.1.0-alpha02"
    def room_version = "2.1.0-alpha04"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Demo project is working but main project is crashing. How can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 23):

You are using the new [Material Components for Android](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/) as a dependency and not the "old" [Android Design Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features). However you are referencing the string `android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior` from the old library which isn't there anymore. So in order to make it work simply change the `app:layout_behavior` from

```
android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior
```

to

```
com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior
```